# How to pass props in BootstrapVue to router-link

Tags: vue.js, navbar, bootstrap-vue

Here is how BootstrapVue's navbar is used https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/navbar, but for one view I need to pass a prop to it from the navbar.

It's pretty easy to add it in raw Vue but BootstrapVue seems not have a solution for that. Does anybody have any clue?

Here is a working copy,

```
<b-nav-item to="/login">register</b-nav-item>
```

I want to change it to something like:

```
<b-nav-item to="/login" :action="'register'">register</b-nav-item>
```

where "action" is my the prop I need to pass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use query parameters on your `:to` prop by using a [`Location` object](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#to):

```html
<b-nav-item :to="{ path: '/login' query: { action: 'register'} }">
  register
</b-nav-item>
```

Or if your route is set up for a parameter slug (i.e. `/login/:action'):

```html
<b-nav-item :to="{ path: '/login' params: { action: 'register'} }">
  register
</b-nav-item>
```

If you are using named routes, you can just adjust the above to use `name` instead of `path`.

Comment: theres a comma missing after 'login'

Answer (score 1):

You should just pass `action` as a param in the route URL.  Then in your route declaration, you can assign a `prop` for that route that comes from the URL. I would format the URL like so:

```
<b-nav-item to="/login?action=register">register</b-nav-item>
```

Then in your path declaration, use something like this:

```
{
  path: 'login',
  name: 'login',
  component: Login,
  props: (route) => ({ action: route.query.action })
}
```

Comment: That was my workaround. and also it should be `route.query.action` there. Thanks anyway.

Comment: help here with related question please. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58822854/how-to-pass-pass-pramas-in-b-nav-item-using-store-getters