# How to pass pass pramas in b-nav-item using store getters?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

My route is like this -

```
 {
      path: '/user/:uid/myorders',
      name: 'my-orders',
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "user-orders" */ './admin/UserOrdersPage.vue'),
      meta: { requiresLogin: true },
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        checkForAuth(to, next);
      }
    },
```

I need to pass uid value from store.getters in b-nav-item element to navigate the page using uid from store.

This is what I am doing right now.

```
<b-nav-item href="#" v-if="this.$store.getters.isUser" tag="router-link" :to= "{name: 'my-orders' params: {uid: this.$store.getters.isUser}}">My Orders</b-nav-item>
```

Error it throws: 
  **Raw expression: :to="{name: 'my-orders' params: {uid: this.$store.getters.user_uid}}"
'v-bind' directives require an attribue**

[image]
I'm pretty new in vue.js dont understand this error as well.

Comment: just missing colon before `params` ?

Comment: I just tried that. didnt work

Comment: Also don't use `this` in templates

Comment: omg, remove space after `:to=`

Comment: that didnt work either

Comment: Add a comma before params

Comment: @MJ_Wales Thanks it worked.

Comment: @Michal Levy thanks for finding that extra space as well

Answer (score 0):

This worked. it was missing , before params.

```
<b-nav-item href="#" v-if="this.$store.getters.isUser" :to="{name: 'my-orders', params: {uid: this.$store.getters.user_uid}}">My Orders</b-nav-item>
```